# hive Expression Not In Group By Key

Tags: group-by, hive, hiveql

I create a table in HIVE.
It has the following columns:

```
id bigint, rank bigint, date string
```

I want to get avg(rank) per month. I can use this command. It works.

```
select a.lens_id, avg(a.rank)
from tableA a
group by a.lens_id, year(a.date_saved), month(a.date_saved);
```

However, I also want to get date information. I use this command:

```
select a.lens_id, avg(a.rank), a.date_saved
from lensrank_archive a
group by a.lens_id, year(a.date_saved), month(a.date_saved);
```

It complains: `Expression Not In Group By Key`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The full error message should be in the format `Expression Not In Group By Key [value]`.
The `[value]` will tell you what expression needs to be in the `Group By`.

Just looking at the two queries, I'd say that you need to add `a.date_saved` explicitly to the `Group By`.

Comment: Yes. After adding a.date_saved, it works. However, it does not do what I want. I want avg(rank) per month. Now it does not do average. It just shows all records since adding group by a.date_saved.

Comment: @chnet: You can't have a column selected and not have it grouped by that column. If you want to display `a.date_saved` you need to group by it. You might be able to display `year(a.date_saved)` and `month(a.date_saved)` since those are in the `Group by` but not 100% on that.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to display year(a.date_saved) and month(a.date_saved).

Comment: what do you mean ? is it something unique for HQL? i am doing group by with not all columns in MySQL and it work'd fine

Comment: No help. fix by collect_set()[0]

Answer (score 14):

A walk around is to put the additional field in a collect_set and return the first element of the set. For example

```
select a.lens_id, avg(a.rank), collect_set(a.date_saved)[0]
from lensrank_archive a
group by a.lens_id, year(a.date_saved), month(a.date_saved);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is more than one ‘date_saved’ record under your group by. You can turn these ‘date_saved’ records into arrays and output them.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and maybe show an example, or just post it as a comment to the question.)