# Error in group by using hive

Tags: hive

I am using the following code and getting the error below

```
      select d.searchpack,d.context, d.day,d,txnid,d.config, c.sgtype from ds3resultstats d join       
     context_header c on (d.context=c.contextid) where (d.day>='2012-11-15' and d.day<='2012-11-25' and  c.sgtype='Tickler' and d.config like 
'%people%') GROUP BY d.context limit 10;
        FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 1:7 Expression Not In Group By Key d
```

I am guessing I am using the group by incorrectly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you use `group by`, you cannot select other additional field. You can only select group key with aggregate function.

See [hive group by](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-groupby.html) for more information.

[Related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746687/hive-expression-not-in-group-by-key).

Code example:

```
select d.context,count(*)
from ds3resultstats
...
group by d.context
```

or group by multiply fields.

```
select d.context, d.field2, count(*)
from ds3resultstats
...
group by d.context, d.field2
```

Answer (score 2):

It is expecting all the columns to be added with group by.
Even I am facing the same issue however I managed to get a work around to these kind of issues.
you can use `collect_set` with the column name to get the output. For example 
`select d.searchpack,collect_set(d.context) from sampletable group by d.searchpack;`